# How can I get the blog page ID?

Tags: pages, blog

As above, for example this is the blog page url:

`http://192.168.1.100/wordpress/?page_id=30`

Let assume that I don't know the exact ID of blog page and I want to write `if` condition for this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the blog page id using this:

```
get_option('page_for_posts');
```

Comment: Note: This will return `0` if `Front page displays` (in Settings > Reading) is set to the `"Your latest posts"` option.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the page/post editor and hover your mouse over the edit link without clicking, you'll see at the bottom of the browser window the url info for that link which will include the post id.  That is how I find them.  Not sure exactly how to do that with php though.  I'm sure there is something that would help you over in the WP codex though.

Comment: I guess the question is about getting the blog id dynamically through codes. :)